# Snowflake get_path() or flatten() array query - to find latest key:value

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column 'amp' in a table 'EXAMPLE'. Column 'amp' is an array which looks like this:

```js
[{
  "list": [{
    "element": {
      "x_id": "12356789XXX",
      "y_id": "12356789XXX38998",
    }
  },
  {
    "element": {
      "x_id": "5677888356789XXX",
      "y_id": "1XXX387688",
    }
  }]
}]
```

How should I query using `get_path()` or `flatten()` to extract the latest `x_id` and `y_id` value (or other alternative)

In this example it is only 2 elements, but there could 1 to 6000 elements containing `x_id` and `y_id`.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure where the time is, to find latest?

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Sorry I forgot to mention the last x_id and y_id are the latest ones (in this case the 2nd element)

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have a more elegant way than this, but you can use a CTE. In the first table expression, grab the max of the array. In the second part, grab the values you need.

```
set json = '[{"list": [{"element": {"x_id": "12356789XXX","y_id": "12356789XXX38998"}},{"element": {"x_id": "5677888356789XXX","y_id": "1XXX387688",}}]}]';
create temp table foo(v variant);
insert into foo select parse_json($json);

with 
MAX_INDEX(M) as
(
    select max("INDEX") MAX_INDEX
    from foo, lateral flatten(v, recursive => true)
),
VALS(V, P, K) as 
(
    select "VALUE", "PATH", "KEY"
    from foo, lateral flatten(v, recursive => true)
)

select k as "KEY", V::string as VALUE  from vals, max_index
    where VALS.P = '[0].list[' || max_index.m || '].element.x_id' or
          VALS.P = '[0].list[' || max_index.m || '].element.y_id'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the outer array ALWAYS contains a single dictionary element, you could use this:

```
SELECT amp[0]:"list"[ARRAY_SIZE(amp[0]:"list")-1]:"element":"x_id"::VARCHAR AS x_id
      ,amp[0]:"list"[ARRAY_SIZE(amp[0]:"list")-1]:"element":"y_id"::VARCHAR AS y_id
  FROM T
;
```

Or if you prefer a bit more modularity/readability, you could use this:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
  SELECT amp[0]:"list" AS _ARRAY
    FROM T
)
,CTE2 AS (
  SELECT _ARRAY[ARRAY_SIZE(_ARRAY)-1]:"element" AS _DICT
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT _DICT:"x_id"::VARCHAR AS x_id
      ,_DICT:"y_id"::VARCHAR AS y_id
  FROM CTE2
;
```

Note: I have not used FLATTEN here because I did not see a good reason to use it.